# Low amount of HDD Minimum transfer rate

Tags: hard-drive, transfer-rate, hd-tune

Recently i used HDTune app to measure my HDD info.
I've noticed i get a huge drop and i'm having low amount of "minimum HDD transfer".
Is it normal? Or im just getting too sensitive afterwards of installing W10?
I ran 3 different tests. and no, there were no additional apps running in background(Besides telegram and WMP, which i assume they don't use much of HDD resources)
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsqJ5.png)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaHIl.png)
[Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZYnW.png)
Specs:
ST1000DM003-9YN162 1TB
6GB RAM
G620 2.6GHZ CPU
W10 Pro

Comment: How is it connected?

Comment: @DavidPostill Not quite sure, i was just about to ask whether its normal or not.

Comment: What is WMP? This is not an abbreviation I ever heard about.

Comment: @r2d3 Windows Media Player.

Comment: You do not state if your drive in question is the system drive or not.

Comment: Assuming instead of excluding is not a good way of testing.

Comment: @r2d3 thanks for the comment.
Btw, HDTune checks the whole disk. screenshots which are provided belong to the whole HDD 1TB drive, not just one drive.

Comment: What do you mean with "not just one drive"? You did not comment on: "You do not state if your drive in question is the system drive or not."

Comment: Sorry, i meant the whole HDD "Disk" .
I mean, HDTune scans for errors in the whole HDD.( which means like C: D: E: together and at once, not one by one.)
I have only 1 HDD installed at the moment.

Comment: C:, D: and E: are called partitions or volumes. 
If your operating system is running on your one and only drive you should not wonder why your HDTune is being interrupted by the operating system causing dropdowns in transfer rate.
Your experimental setup is not suitable for your question.

Comment: @r2d3 you're right, my bad. thank you.